# Display Image in Django

Tags: django

I've been unable to make this work although I realise there are similar questions. Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I have a django app which allows uploads of images with it. Right now my model looks like this.

The image is not displaying for some reason when it is called from the code. The reasons I can imagine are in the view.py file, or how I am calling it in the template file.

Appreciate your help in advance,

MODELS

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to="locations/%Y/%m/%D")
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

VIEWS

```
def index(request):
    # Query the databse for a list of ALL categories currently stored.
    # Order the categories by no likes in descending order .
    # Retrieve the top 5 only - or all if less than 5.
    # Place the list in context_dict dictionary
    # that will be passed to the template engine.
    category_list = Category.objects.order_by('-likes')[:5]
    page_list = Page.objects.order_by('-views')[:5]

    context_dict = {'categories': category_list, 'pages': page_list}

    # Render the response and send it back!

    return render(request, 'Spaces/index.html', context_dict)


def show_category(request, category_name_slug):
    # Create a context dictionary which we can pass
    # to the template rendering engine.
    context_dict = {}

    try:
        # Can we find a category name slug with the given name?
        # If we can't, the .get() method raises a DoesNotExist exception.
        # So the .get() method returns one model instance or raises an exception.
        category = Category.objects.get(slug=category_name_slug)
        # Retrieve all of the associated pages.
        # Note that filter() returns a list of page objects or an empty list
        pages = Page.objects.filter(category=category)

        # Adds our results list to the template context under name pages.
        context_dict['pages'] = pages
        # We also add the category object from
        # the database to the context dictionary.
        # We'll use this in the template to verify that the category exists.
        context_dict['category'] = category

        # We get here if we didn't find the specified category.
        # Don't do anything -
        # the template will display the "no category" message for us.
    except Category.DoesNotExist:
        context_dict['category'] = None
        context_dict['pages'] = None
        # Go render the response and return it to the client.
    return render(request, 'Spaces/category.html', context_dict)
```

TEMPLATES

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load i18n %}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Side Spacer</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

  <!-- Navigation -->

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="#"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">

            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Spaces</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/Spaces/about/">How it works</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a></li>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log out {{user.username}}</a></li>
        {% else %}
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'signup' %}">Sign Up</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a></li>
        {% endif %}
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>

</nav>

<!--- Image Slider -->

<div id="slides" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="0"class="active"></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">

            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3 class="display-2">Need a workspace on the go?</h3>
                <h3>Great locations and flexible pricing!</h3>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg" href="{% url 'signup' %}">Join Now!</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<!--- Jumbotron -->
<hr class="my-4">

<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row jumbotron">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-xl-10">
            <p class="lead">For mobile professionals, startups, and business that need the extra deskpace!<br> Productive workspaces are available to help you get things done!<br> Our plans start at $99/month! </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-2">
                <a href="#"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-lg">Our Services</button></a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
            <div class="container">
              <!-- Example row of columns -->
              <div class ="row">
                <div class ="col">
                  <h2>Most Viewed Spaces</h2>
              {% if categories %}
              <ul>
                {% for category in categories %}
                  <li>
                                            {% if item != None %}
                                        <img src="{% get_media_prefix %}{{ category.image }}" width="500px" />
                                            {% endif %}
                    <a href="/Spaces/category/{{ category.slug }}">{{ category.name }}</a>
                  </li>
                  {% endfor %}
              </ul>
              {% else %}
                <strong>There are no Spaces present.</strong>
              {% endif %}

                </div>
                  <div class ="col">
                    <h2>Most Viewed Events</h2>
                      <p>
                            {% if pages %}
                                <ul>
                            {% for page in pages %}
                                <li><a href="{{ page.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a></span></li>
                             {% endfor %}
                               </ul>
                            {% else %}
                                <strong>There are no Events present.</strong>
                         {% endif %}
                        </p>
                  </div>
                <div>
                                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
              <div>
                <p><a class="btn btn-success" href="/Spaces/add_category/" role="button">Add New Space »</a></p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-success" href="/Spaces/add_page/" role="button">Create New Event »</a></p>
              </div>
                                {% endif %}
            </div> <!-- /container -->
              <hr>


              <div class="container-fluid padding">
                <div class="row text-center">

                    <div class="col-md-4">

                        <hr class="light">
                        <img src="#">
                        <hr class="light">
                        <p>555-555-55555</p>
                        <p>email@someonesmail.com</p>
                        <p>100 Street name</p>
                        <p>City, State, 0000</p>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">

                        <hr class="light">
                        <h5>Our hours</h5>
                        <hr class="light">
                        <p>Monday: 9AM - 5PM</p>
                        <p>Saturday: 10AM - 4PM</p>
                        <p>Sunday: Closed</p>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">

                            <hr class="light">
                            <h5>Service Area</h5>
                            <hr class="light">
                            <p>City, State, 0000</p>
                            <p>City, State, 0000</p>
                            <p>City, State, 0000</p>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-12">

                        <hr class="light">
                        <h5>&copy; nameofthebusiness </h5>

                    </div>

                </div>
              </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery-slim.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
  <script src="../../assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have not added {% load static %} before get_media_prefix, the better way is to add {{ category.image.url }} .

Comment: So should I add load static first?

Comment: Yes. It should be `{% load static %} <img src=" your src "> `

Comment: I'm taking the image from a model file ( the url that is) so the url has to be dynamically linked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

```
{% if item != None %}
 <img src="{% get_media_prefix %}{{ category.image }}" width="500px" />
                                            {% endif %}
```

Changed too

```
{% if category.image %}
<img src="{{ category.image.url }}"  />
{% endif %}
```

Problem solved

Answer (score 3):

You have to add get_media_prefix before the image. I use {{ category.image.url }} to serve media from AWS S3, but I think here you would just use {{ category.image }}. Play with it a little bit and see.

```
 <img src="{% get_media_prefix %}{{ category.image }}" width="500px" />
```

Comment: This gave me this error,

"TemplateSyntaxError at /
Invalid block tag on line 99: 'get_media_prefix', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?"

Comment: Try adding {% load i18n %} to your template.

Comment: Just at the top or within the image SRC

Comment: Just at the top.

Comment: "Invalid block tag on line 102: 'get_media_prefix', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?"

Comment: Given loading i18n + leaving the code you mentioned in

Comment: Done! Thanks Whodini

Comment: I think it's the view file

Comment: Oh thought you had it. Try moving {% load staticfiles %}
{% load i18n %} within the template's head.

Comment: What is load i18n doing?

Comment: Still getting this error "TemplateSyntaxError at /
Invalid block tag on line 100: 'get_media_prefix', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?"

Comment: @MichaelHolborn - It allows translation. It was a long shot. I was just giving you things to try. The last things I can advise you to try is change {% load staticfiles %} to {% load static %}, and make sure your app is properly configured to serve media files.

Answer (score 0):

You should give proper path for the image. for me below code works properly.

in settings:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

to display image

```
<img src="/media/{{category.image}}" width="500px" />
```

Comment: I have those settings and with that code linked it does not load unfortunately